# How to invoke command-line tool in C++

Tags: c++

I want to develop an improved version of OpenSSH, and it depends on OpenSSL to generate the RSA and DSA keys to encrypt and sign the connection data. But it seems that I cannot call OpenSSL with `fork()`. Can someone tell me how to call `openssl genrsa 8192` in my C++ code so I would not need to write a shell script for it? I have prepared a prime generator for RSA and DSA if this fails.

Comment: How about just calling it with `system()`?

Comment: And why do you want to use `fork()`

Comment: @klutt I think that fork creates a subprocess which makes sense. btw how to use `system()`

Comment: An "improved" OpenSSH were someone can replace the key generation? No, thank you. Use the libcrypto part of OpenSSL as a library instead.

Comment: @PythonCoder If you just want to run a quick command, creating a sub process does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `system` library function to invoke external programs.  You pass the command line in a string, like `system ("openssl genrsa 8192 >key.rsa")`, then you need to read the result back from the file "key.rsa".

Comment: popen is probably better so you don't create a file, just read process output

Comment: I do not know how to make an input stream out of `popen`. GNU has `stdiostream` but that is nonstandard.

Comment: `FILE *f = popen("openssl genrsa 8192");` then read from `f` and `pclose(f)` in the end

Comment: `FILE` is not an input stream.

Comment: `FILE` is a file handle from `stdio.h` that works in C++. It's standard. You just have to know the worst case for the memory allocation or use getline and grow your buffer

Comment: A `FILE` is a bare resource handle.  It can only be used with exceptions disabled.